# Missable side quests after completing The Nameless quest

Tags: ps4, the-witcher-3

I've been reading in forums that after "The Nameless" quest in The Witcher 3, you can miss some side quests. Is this true? I have several side quests to do, and I'm currently at The Nameless quest. Should I return and do all the side quests or will they be there after completing The Nameless quest?

Comment: What forums have you been reading that point you to this conclusion?

Comment: @ChaseC GameFAQs and such, even Steam Forums. (Can't find the links any more) Also, here: https://www.vg247.com/2015/05/12/the-witcher-3-nameless-walkthrough/ there's a warning at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The quests "Now or never" and the quest "A deadly plot" must be concluded. After you have finished the quest "Nameless", you can't do them anymore.You can try it out: Keep a savegame before you jump down to the pit in the garden of the Freya priestesses on Hindarsfjall from which you will salvage the corps.The main quest will proceed for 15 minutes after salvaging but afterwards the game will indicate the two mentioned quests as failed.